# how to add different JComboBox items in a Column of a JTable in Swing

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox, tablecellrenderer

I want to add JComboBox inside a JTable (3,3) on column 1. But in the column 1 , each row will have its own set of ComboBox element. 
When I tried to use

```
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox_Custom));
```

Each row is being set to same set of ComboBox Values. 
But I want each row ComboBox has different items.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

example on [java2s.com](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/EachRowwithdifferentEditorExample.htm) looks like as works and correctly, then for example (I harcoded JComboBoxes for quick example, and add/change for todays Swing)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class EachRowEditorExample extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public EachRowEditorExample() {
        super("EachRow Editor Example");
        try {
            for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                System.out.println(info.getName());
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            // handle exception
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // handle exception
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            // handle exception
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // handle exception
        }
        DefaultTableModel dm = new DefaultTableModel();
        dm.setDataVector(new Object[][]{{"Name", "MyName"}, {"Gender", "Male"}, {"Color", "Fruit"}}, new Object[]{"Column1", "Column2"});
        JTable table = new JTable(dm);
        table.setRowHeight(20);
        JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
        comboBox.addItem("Male");
        comboBox.addItem("Female");
        comboBox.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
                final JComponent c = (JComponent) e.getSource();
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        c.requestFocus();
                        System.out.println(c);
                        if (c instanceof JComboBox) {
                            System.out.println("a");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });


        JComboBox comboBox1 = new JComboBox();
        comboBox1.addItem("Name");
        comboBox1.addItem("MyName");
        comboBox1.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
                final JComponent c = (JComponent) e.getSource();
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        c.requestFocus();
                        System.out.println(c);
                        if (c instanceof JComboBox) {
                            System.out.println("a");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        JComboBox comboBox2 = new JComboBox();
        comboBox2.addItem("Banana");
        comboBox2.addItem("Apple");
        comboBox2.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
                final JComponent c = (JComponent) e.getSource();
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        c.requestFocus();
                        System.out.println(c);
                        if (c instanceof JComboBox) {
                            System.out.println("a");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        EachRowEditor rowEditor = new EachRowEditor(table);
        rowEditor.setEditorAt(0, new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox1));
        rowEditor.setEditorAt(1, new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox));
        rowEditor.setEditorAt(2, new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox2));
        table.getColumn("Column2").setCellEditor(rowEditor);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
        getContentPane().add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 120));
        setLocation(150, 100);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EachRowEditorExample frame = new EachRowEditorExample();
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

just add EachRowEditor Class

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.atos.table.classes;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;

public class PartCustomerWindow2 {
    public static final Object[][] DATA = { { 1, 2,3, 4,false }, { 5, 6,7, 8 ,true},{ 9, 10,11, 12,true }, { 13, 14,15, 16,true } };

    public static final String[] COL_NAMES = { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four",MyTableModel1.SELECT };

    JButton but = new JButton("Add");
    private JComboBox jcomboBox = null;
    private JTextField jTextField = null;

    static Object[][] rowData = null;
    private JTable table=null;
    static   JFrame frame = null;
    HashMap mp = null;
    static int count = 0;
    String content = null;


    public JTextField getjTextField() {
        if(jTextField == null)
        {
            jTextField =  new FMORestrictedTextField(FMORestrictedTextField.JUST_ALPHANUMERIC, 8);
        }

    mp = new HashMap();
        mp.put("arif",2);
        mp.put("8",6);
        mp.put("12",10);
        mp.put("14",16);
        mp.put("pk1",22);
        mp.put("pk3",23);

             jTextField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

             public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event) {


                 if(count == 0)
                 content = jTextField.getText();
                // System.out.println(content);

                 if(mp.containsKey(content))
                 {
                     JFrame parent = new JFrame();

                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(parent, "Already Assigned"); 
                 }
                 }

         });
        return jTextField;
    }


    public void setjTextField(JTextField jTextField) {
        this.jTextField = jTextField;
    }


   public JComboBox getJcomboBox() {
       if(jcomboBox == null)
       {
           jcomboBox = new JComboBox();
       }
        return jcomboBox;
    }


    public void setJcomboBox(JComboBox jcomboBox) {
        this.jcomboBox = jcomboBox;
    }


private void createAndShowGui(PartCustomerWindow2 ob)
   {
     /*rowData  = new Object[DATA.length][];
      for (int i = 0; i < rowData.length; i++) {
         rowData[i] = new Object[DATA[i].length + 1];
         for (int j = 0; j < DATA[i].length; j++) {
            rowData[i][j] = DATA[i][j];
         }
         rowData[i][DATA[i].length] = Boolean.TRUE;
         if(i == 2 || i ==3)
             rowData[i][DATA[i].length] = Boolean.FALSE;
      }*/

      MyTableModel3 tableModel = new MyTableModel3(DATA, COL_NAMES, "My Table", ob);


      table = new JTable(tableModel);

      //table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

      /*table.addFocusListener(new java.awt.event.FocusAdapter() {
          public void focusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
            table.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
          }
        });*/

      TableColumnModel cm = table.getColumnModel();


      /*cm.getColumn(2).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(

                new JComboBox(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {
                 "Yes",
                  "No",
                  "Maybe"
                }))));*/
     /* String ar1[]= {"aa","aaa","aaaa"};
      ob.getJcomboBox().setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(ar1));*/
      cm.getColumn(2).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(

              ob.getJcomboBox()));


      cm.getColumn(3).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(

              ob.getjTextField()));


      JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
     /* scrollPane.add("Table",table);
      scrollPane.add("Button",but);*/

      JFrame frame2 =  new JFrame();
     /* jcomboBox.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,20));
      textField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,20));
      jcomboBox.setEnabled(false);
      textField.setEnabled(false);
      */
      JScrollPane scrollPane2 = new JScrollPane(but);

      but.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {


        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(table.getCellEditor() != null)
            table.getCellEditor().stopCellEditing();
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String[][] ar = new String[table.getRowCount()][5];


            for(int i =0;i<table.getRowCount();i++)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
                {
                    DATA[i][j] = table.getValueAt(i,j);
                }

                System.out.print(table.getValueAt(i,0)+" ");
                System.out.print(table.getValueAt(i,1)+" ");
                System.out.print(table.getValueAt(i,2)+" ");
                System.out.print(table.getValueAt(i,3)+" ");
                System.out.println(table.getValueAt(i,4)+" ");
            }

        System.out.println("*******************");
        /*
            for(int i=0;i<DATA.length;i++)
            {
                System.out.print(DATA[i][0]);
                System.out.print(DATA[i][1]);
                System.out.print(DATA[i][2]);
                System.out.print(DATA[i][3]);
                boolean check =(Boolean) DATA[i][4];
                System.out.println(check);
            }*/

    }});


      frame = new JFrame("PartCustomerWindow2");
      //
      //JFrame frame = new JFrame();
      Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
      contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      contentPane.add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.NORTH);
      contentPane.add(but);


      //
      //frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

     /* frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane2);
      frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane3);
      frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane4);*/
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);


   }





public static void main(String[] args) {
       PartCustomerWindow2 ob = new PartCustomerWindow2();

       ob.createAndShowGui(ob);

   }
}



































@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MyTableModel3 extends DefaultTableModel {
   public static final String SELECT = "select";
   String tablename;
   PartCustomerWindow2 ob = null;



   public MyTableModel3(Object[][] rowData, Object[] columnNames, String tableName,PartCustomerWindow2 ob) {
      super(rowData, columnNames);
      this.tablename = tableName;
      this.ob = ob;

   }

   @Override
   public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
      if (getColumnName(columnIndex).equalsIgnoreCase(SELECT)) {

         return Boolean.class;
      }
      else

      return super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
       JComboBox jb = ob.getJcomboBox();
       JTextField jt = ob.getjTextField();

       if(((Boolean) getValueAt(row, getColumnCount() - 1)).booleanValue())
       {

         //  jb.setEnabled(false);

          jb.removeAllItems();
          // System.out.println(jb.getItemCount());
          if(row == 0)
          {
             jb.addItem("arif");
              jb.addItem("asif");
               jb.addItem("ashik");
               jb.addItem("farooq");
               jb.addItem("adkh");

          }

          if(row > 0)
          {
             jb.addItem("kjhds");
               jb.addItem("sdds");
               jb.addItem("asdfsdk");
               jb.addItem("sdfsdf");
               jb.addItem("sdf");
          }

        /*HashMap mp = new HashMap();
        mp.put("arif",2);
        mp.put("8",6);
        mp.put("12",10);
        mp.put("14",16);
        mp.put("pk1",22);
        mp.put("pk3",23);
          */
        /* if(col == 3){

        if(mp.containsKey(jt.getText()))
          {
            System.out.println("Sorry..!! already assigned");
            jt.setFocusable(true);
          }

           jt.setText("");
           jt.setEnabled(false);
       }*/
       }
       else
       {
          // jb.setEnabled(true);
           //jt.setEnabled(true);
       }

       if (col == getColumnCount()-1 ) {

         return true;
       }
      else{
          if (getColumnName(4).equalsIgnoreCase(SELECT) && ((Boolean) getValueAt(row, getColumnCount() - 1)).booleanValue())
          {  
            //  jb.setEnabled(true);


             // jt.setEnabled(true);
              return (col == 2 || col == 3);

          }
          else{
             // jb.setEnabled(false);
              //jt.setEnabled(false);
              return false;
          }


      }

   }





}
```

Comment: This post will help you to add a selection checkbox in JTable and when selecting it enables the specific columns of that row and also having different item values for comboBox of each row

Comment: Please explain a bit your code in the answer, as it is a bit long and will be easier for the community to understand it

Comment: This code helps you to add different ComboBox items in each row, as I'm passing Hashmap, If the first col as key in hashmap, I'm assigning the items as per the first value.

Comment: MyTableModel is TableModel which having the cell editable functionality