# java: Access a JProgressBar in an AbstractTableModel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, abstracttablemodel

I'm working with the following code that contains a JProgressBar inside of an AbstractTableModel. The JProgressBar progress value is updated in "case 5: " of the getValueAt() function by returning a Float. What I'm trying to figure out is how to access the underlying JProgressBar instance so I can modify some of it's properties other than the progress value (such as setVisible()).

```
package org.jdamico.jhu.runtime;

import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

// This class manages the upload table's data.
class TransfersTableModel extends AbstractTableModel implements Observer {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2740117506937325535L;

    // These are the names for the table's columns.
    private static final String[] columnNames = { "Type","Name", "UUID","Status",
            "Stage","Progress","Total Start Time","Total End Time" };

    // These are the classes for each column's values.
    private static final Class[] columnClasses = { String.class,String.class,String.class, 
            String.class,String.class, JProgressBar.class, String.class, String.class};

    // The table's list of uploads.
    private ArrayList<ParentEntry> transferList = new ArrayList<ParentEntry>();

    // Add a new upload to the table.
    public void addTransfer(ParentEntry pe) {

        // Register to be notified when the upload changes.
        pe.addObserver(this);

        transferList.add(pe);

        // Fire table row insertion notification to table.
        fireTableRowsInserted(getRowCount(), getRowCount());
    }

    // Get a upload for the specified row.
    public ParentEntry getTransfer(int row) {
        return transferList.get(row);
    }

    // Remove a upload from the list.
    public void clearTransfer(int row) {
        transferList.remove(row);

        // Fire table row deletion notification to table.
        fireTableRowsDeleted(row, row);
    }

    // Get table's column count.
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    // Get a column's name.
    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        return columnNames[col];
    }

    // Get a column's class.
    public Class getColumnClass(int col) {
        return columnClasses[col];
    }

    // Get table's row count.
    public int getRowCount() {
        return transferList.size();
    }

    // Get value for a specific row and column combination.
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {

        ParentEntry pe = transferList.get(row);
        switch (col) {
        case 0:
            return pe.getType();
        case 1: // URL
            return pe.getUrl();
        case 2: //UUID
            return pe.getUUID() + "";
        case 3: // Status
            return pe.getStatus().getDisplay();
        case 4: // Stage
            return pe.getStage().getDisplay();
        case 5: //Progress
            return new Float(pe.getProgress());
        case 6:
            if (pe.getTotalStartTime() != null)
                return pe.getTotalStartTime().getTime().toString();
            else
                return "";
        case 7:
            if (pe.getTotalEndTime() != null)
                return pe.getTotalEndTime().getTime().toString();
            else
                return "";
        }
        return "";
    }

    /*
     * Update is called when a Upload notifies its observers of any changes
     */
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        int index = transferList.indexOf(o);

        // Fire table row update notification to table.
        fireTableRowsUpdated(index, index);
    }
}
```

Update: This wasn't originally my code and I'm still familiarizing myself with it, but I just discovered that there was a ProgressRenderer class that extends JProgressBar and implements TableCellRenderer. This is what is being used to render the progress bar in the table. So I'm going to alter this code to alter how the progress bar is being displayed:

```
package org.jdamico.jhu.runtime;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

/*import org.jdamico.jhu.components.Controller;
import org.jdamico.jhu.components.FilePartition;
import org.vikulin.utils.Constants;*/

// This class renders a JProgressBar in a table cell.
class ProgressRenderer extends JProgressBar implements TableCellRenderer {




    // Constructor for ProgressRenderer.
    public ProgressRenderer(int min, int max) {
        super(min, max);
    }

    /*
     * Returns this JProgressBar as the renderer for the given table cell.
     */
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        // Set JProgressBar's percent complete value.
        Float tmp = ((Float) value).floatValue();
        if (tmp == -1) {
            this.setVisible(false);
        }
        else {
            setValue((int) ((Float) value).floatValue());
            if (this.isVisible() == false)
                this.setVisible(true);
        }
        return this;
    }



}
```

Comment: the mantra; separate, separate, separate :-) In particular, never-ever mix view into data classes. It's _wrong_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a method to the class that allows you to get the JProgressBar associated with the row of interest, something like:

```
   public JProgressBar getProgressBar(int row) {
      ParentEntry pe = transferList.get(row);
      return pe.getProgress();
   }
```

It seems kind of funny to me that the model would hold a JProgressBar rather than a simple int representing percentage complete. It would make more sense to me to have any code for progress bar display be in the JTable's cell renderer.

**Edit 1**
In reply to opike's comment below:

> Does it really make the code that much more efficient to use the JProgressBar outside of the model vs inside of it? Is the gain enough so to expend time rewriting the code? The existing code works the way I need it to for the most part so I would prefer just tweaking it vs a more significant rewrite.

My question and my concern is, is your cell renderer using the JProgressBar held by the model? If so, how can it if there is no way for it to obtain the JProgressBar? If it's only using the Float value obtained, it simply makes no sense for the model to hold information and resources that are not used. And yes, this could slow your program down noticeably.

Comment: I don't instantiate the JprogressBar explicitly in my code; the AbstractTableModel handles that implicitly. When the table is repainted the getValueAt() function is called by the event Handler for all of the cells.

Comment: @opike: Right -- the renderer uses the value returned from the model to do its rendering, but why would the model hold a high-resource using widget such as a JProgressBar when all the model returns is a float? Why not just have the model hold the Float? Unless I'm misunderstanding you.

Comment: Does it really make the code that much more efficient to use the JProgressBar outside of the model vs inside of it? Is the gain enough so to expend time rewriting the code? The existing code works the way I need it to for the most part so I would prefer just tweaking it vs a more significant rewrite.

Answer (score 3):

why using AbstractTableModel, nor Adds JTable value inside this code block, really you don't need that, DefalultTableModel can do that, for example

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class ProgressBarTableCellRendererExample {

    private Random random = new Random();
    private JTable table;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ProgressBarTableCellRendererExample().makeUI();
            }
        });
    }

    public void makeUI() {
        table = new JTable(11, 1) {

            private Object[][] data;
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
                return Integer.class;
            }
        };
        randomize();
        table.setDefaultRenderer(Integer.class, new ProgressBarTableCellRenderer());
        table.setRowHeight(20);
        table.setRowMargin(2);
        JButton button = new JButton("Randomize");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                randomize();
                getTableValue();
            }
        });
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocation(150, 150);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 300));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void randomize() {
        for (int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++) {
            table.setValueAt(random.nextInt(100), i, 0);
        }
    }

    private void getTableValue() {
        for (int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++) {
            System.out.println(String.valueOf(table.getValueAt(i, 0)));
        }
    }

    private class ProgressBarTableCellRenderer extends JProgressBar implements TableCellRenderer {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
                boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            setValue((Integer) value);
            System.out.println("Tables Row: " + row + ", Column : " + column + ", has value - " + value);
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it really necessary for me to rework my code to remove the AbstractTableModel? It may be superfluous but it currently works, other than the fact that I don't know how to access the implicitly instantiated JProgressBar in each column.

Comment: @opike not necesssary, but why to restict JTable funcionalities in the AbstractTableModel if DefaltTableModels works, 1) if you start learnt with JTable then is safiest for you look and using DefaltTableModels, 2) your getValueAt is totally contraproductive, 3) I missed some important methods in your Model,  4) from which source you updated your JTable, because, maybe, sure there are exists another ways, then and I think that you wrong asked your question,

Comment: @mKorbel: Myself, I'm OK with use of AbstractTableModel since it gives one greater flexibility on just what you will use as the data nucleus of the model. For instance it allows the OP to use an ArrayList of ParentEntry objects rather than a Vector of non-generic Vectors, but on the flip side it also puts greater responsibility on the OP to make sure that model-view-listener interactions are coded correctly. But I'm not sure how the original poster's getValueAt is contraproductive.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels, that's about Column Class definitions, sure maybe I'd be nearly to agreed with that if each TableCell contains different JComponents in one TableColumn (and contructor in TableCellRenderer talking about JProgresBars with different ranges ??? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261017/how-to-add-different-jcombobox-items-in-a-column-of-a-jtable-in-swing/6261853#6261853  but in this case our magic globes are tired and both we forgot for TableCellEditor), just I'm against complicated simple things,