# How to set JComboBox in specified cell of JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox, cellrenderer

I have a problem. I have been trying to set `JComboBox` in `JTable cell`, but only cell with specified parameters (not all cells in column).

I've customized `DefaultTableCellRenderer` and I'm trying to paste `JComboBox` to cell in `getTableCellRendererComponent`. I know that it place new `JComboBox` exery time when I do sth with `JTable`, it's not a solution of this problem. Maybe somebody knows how it should be done?

Comment: I made some changes in your post, please revert is ....

Comment: Ok, thanks for answer. I'm implementing this solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you'll change something with your Accepted rate, then you can read [my post about that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261017/how-to-add-different-jcombobox-items-in-a-column-of-a-jtable-in-swing/6261853#6261853)