# adding JComboBox to a jTable with specific data per row

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox, tablecelleditor

I am trying to add a `JComboBox` to the last column of my `JTable`. The `JComboBox` isn't for editing purposes but for traversing the `JTable` itself. Each row can have 0-many elements that need to go in the `JComboBox` and when a value is selected from the box I need to scroll to a different row in the `JTable`.

All the research I have done points me specifically to editors and renderers with the down fall being that data in the `JComboBox` is set per column so that a user can select a value for the cell in the row. Where as I need values that are specific to the row.

So my question is, has anyone tried to do this before? and Can you point me to some good information on how to do this? or even better could you describe how you did this?

Comment: It's quite hard to understand what do you want to achieve. Could you post a screenshot of the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1/ simple example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261017/how-to-add-different-jcombobox-items-in-a-column-of-a-jtable-in-swing/6261853#6261853), your job is only to move (hold) `TableCellEditor` to the last row in the `TableView`,

2/ if `JComboBox's Item` changed then search in `TableModel` for `TableRow` (if every `TableColumns` ends with `JComboBox`)

3/ then call `myTable.changeSelection(row, column, false, false);`

4/ possible fauls implemented and used `RowSorter`, `RowFilter`, then you have to get int row from `TableView` and convert that to the `TableModel` by using

```
int modelRow = convertRowIndexToModel(row);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I also found this.
http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip102.html

with both of these sources I will be able to get this.