# JTable, JComboBox dynamic values

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox

I have `JTable`. In it I have few columns. In 3 of them I have `JComboBox` (each column's each cell has unique `JComboBox` - i.e. whole column 1 - "apple", "bannana"; column 2 - "red", "blue"; column 3 - "cat", "dog"). At program start I want them to be empty. Later after few action events I'm filling them. The thing is, it's not enough to add `JComboBox` with same values for each column. Because after adding `JComboBox` to `JTable`, you have to implement `TableCellRenderer` and extend `DefaultCellEditor` or else you can't see `JComboBox` in table unless you click on it (`TableCellRenderer` fault) or instead of comboBox you get just Object.toString() line in cell (`DefaultCellRenderer` fault). So how should I handle `JComboBox`, `TableCellRenderer` and `DefaultCellEditor` so I can dynamicly change values of whole `JComboBox` which is in `JTable`.

Comment: sounds like you do it wrong (or me misunderstanding :-) - you never have a _component_ in a cell. Instead you have a model which holds the _data_ and renderers/editors on the table which viusalize the data

Comment: So you think that in table i should hold for example String[] and when i Override render/editor i get it visualized?

Answer (score 3):

There is one more thing you should consider. It is using a model. The model will to hold the apples and bananas and the cats and dogs. JTable and JComboBox have respectively [AbstractTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html) and [ComboBoxModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ComboBoxModel.html). Check the tutorial for examples.

Comment: Like i mentioned two times above, if you select value in one combobox, all comboboxes with same model (all column) get selected with the same value.

Comment: Each JComboBox should have it's own model.

Comment: Ok, then how should I insert value in for example 800 similar JComboBoxes without changing in each and every one of them? Now i change it for one model, and all comboboxes gets it.

Answer (score 2):

please to read [Using a Combo Box as an Editor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#combobox), because JTable know JComboBox for Renderer and Editor too, examples [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/CatalogSwing-JFC.htm), and example about [EachRowEditor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6261853/714968)

Comment: Thanks this was helpful. But still there is problem that remains. I use one model for all JComboBox in one colum. When i fill or remove values it's ok. But if i select one combo box in one cell all column is selected with same value.

Comment: 'I use one model for all JComboBox in one colum' that right and correct output, but for reall wotring code you have to split that to the separated Models, otherwise you have to split add Items to the COmboBOxModel from hardcoded ranges 1-10, 11-20 , etc.. that not good idea...

Comment: Sorry, didn't really understood what you meant. The problem is not with adding values. If I use one model I can add values like I want (in all JComboBox'es of one column changes are made simetricly). But the problem is when I select anything in one JComboBox, every other JComboBox with same model gets same value selected.

Comment: create JComboBox with own Model, for every JComboBox

Comment: Then again, is it the only way? Because if I need to add an item in all JComboBox'es of that column I have to cycle through them one by one and add it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you would have to override both the TableCellRenderer and DefaultCellEditor to return the same JComboBox.  So you could have a JComboBox passed as an argument to the TableCellRenderer and DefaultCellEditor and then have that JComboBox returned by the getRenderer or getEditor routines of said classes.

Comment: not quite sure what you mean with "same JComboBox" - if you really (as I guess) mean "same instance of" then it's wrong. Never-ever share the same component instance in editor and renderer!

Comment: kleopatra, why is it like this? why shouldn't i share it? should i make 2 instances with same model or smth? but then selection gets complicated, as i mentioned above if you select value in one combobox, all comboboxes with same model (all column) get selected with the same value.

Comment: Actually, I don't think the combo box in the renderer would work because renderers just create graphics that are then copied.  However in the editor, there is only ever one shown at a time so you don't need many copies - the editor just seeds it with the necessary values and current selection.